# Firebase Snapshots not parsing data correctly

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to download latitude and longitude coordinates from Firebase into my app and then display a marker on a map with Google Maps and Google Marker.  I know that the placemark feature works, because when I manually program coordinates I can see the place holder of the other "person" so this is not a Google maps issue.

The problem seems to be twofold, one, the data from Firebase is being "snapped" and when you do a "po snapshot" in the console everything is there, all users and data.  When I initiate the for in loop, is where the problem lies.  When you do a "po driver" it ONLY shows the first user in firebase, but when you do a "po driverSnapshot" it does show the same as "po snapshot"

For some reason Firebase is not letting me parse through the snapshot properly.  I load the snapshot into a dictionary and I can see my data but ONLY the first user, not the others.  regardless, I should be able to then extract the coordinates using ["my/example"] as subscript for Dictionary.  When I try to get the longitude and latitude and put them into an array, so I can display multiple coordinates (longitude and latitude for all users in the "snap") this is not working.

Ideal I would like to fix both issues.  First get rid of the Unexpectedly found nil error and then figure out why I am only getting one user when I have 3 with the same information.

Any assistance on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.  I did do a pod Update and am running the latest firebase.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
func loadMarkersFromFB1() {
    DataService.instance.REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let driverSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for driver in driverSnapshot {
                    if driver.childSnapshot(forPath: ACCOUNT_PICKUP_MODE_ENABLED).value as? Bool == true {
                        if let driverDict = driver.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            let coordinateArray = driverDict[DRIVERCOORDINATE] as! NSArray **THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING NIL ERROR**
                            print(coordinateArray)
                            let driverCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinateArray[0] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: coordinateArray[1] as! CLLocationDegrees)
                        //    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                let othermarker = GMSMarker()
                                othermarker.position = driverCoordinate
                        //      othermarker.userData = snap
                                othermarker.icon = UIImage(named: "driverAnnotation")
                                othermarker.map = self.driverMapView
                        //    })
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.showAlert("Test")
                    }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the JSON:

```
 "users" : {
    "123456789123456789" : {
      "driver_profile" : {
        "currentlocation" : [ 55.55555, -55.55555555 ],
        "isDriverStatusPending" : false,
        "isPickupModeEnabled" : true,
        "is_userdriver" : true
      },
      "first_name" : "Carlos",
      "last_name" : "Santana",
      "mobile_number" : "2125551212",
      "provider" : "Firebase"
    },
    "2398472398472398472398472384" : {
      "driver_profile" : {
        "currentlocation" : [ 55.55555, -55.55555555 ],
        "isDriverStatusPending" : false,
        "isPickupModeEnabled" : true,
        "is_userdriver" : true
      },
      "first_name" : "Mick",
      "last_name" : "Jagger",
      "mobile_number" : "3125551212",
      "provider" : "Firebase",
      "stripe_id" : "1234354954",
      "userAddressInfo" : {
        "Home" : {
          "City" : "Anywhere",
          "State" : "AA",
          "Street" : "123 Any Street",
          "Zip" : "12345"
        }
      },
      "userPhoto" : "http://www.myphoto.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't driver be only 1 user since driverSnapshot is an array of users? Also, what is the nil error? Can you give us more information what DRIVERCOORDINATE is?

Comment: Please add the JSON from `REF_USERS`, as text, no screenshots. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Use Swift construct `Array` instead of Obj-C `NSArray`

Comment: I would suggest using `Any` instead of `AnyObject` as well. It is possible it is the casting of it to the `NSArray` causing it to be nil. Have you tried adding a `print(driverDict)` above your failing line? What does it print?

Comment: @Mocha What do you mean only use 1?  Yes driverSnapshot is the array of users, but I need it to go through every user and look for the value of users/driver_profile/currentlocation.  The nil error is" Unexpectiedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" . DRIVERCOORDINATE is a constant.  I am sorry I should have edited it.  is is the firebase path

Comment: @Greg When you po snapshot you get an array of users. So if you do a for loop over the snapshot, each iteration will be one user? Have you tried to po snapshot[1] to see if the array is ONLY being populated by the first user?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have put the JSON in the post.

Comment: @Jeremiah I tried that already but the same result.  When i do a print(driverDict) it shows the first user listed above in my JSON. it shows all the keys and values

Comment: If you are able to retrieve driverDict, maybe check if your DRIVERCOORDINATE is really "currentlocation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be due to a couple of things

1) Your path's are not correct per Frank's answer

2) The processing of the driver_profile child node

I took your structure and imported it into Firebase and then altered your code to make it work.

First thing was hard coding the two variables which were not included in the question. The second thing was treating the driver_profile child node as it's own dictionary to read the data from within that node.

```
func loadMarkersFromFB1() {

    let ACCOUNT_PICKUP_MODE_ENABLED = "driver_profile/isPickupModeEnabled"
    let DRIVERCOORDINATE = "currentlocation"
    let ref = self.ref.child("users")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let driverSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for driver in driverSnapshot {
                if driver.childSnapshot(forPath: ACCOUNT_PICKUP_MODE_ENABLED).value as? Bool == true {
                    if let driverDict = driver.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let lastName = driverDict["last_name"] as! String
                        let childDict = driverDict["driver_profile"] as![String: Any] //**
                        let currentLocation = childDict[DRIVERCOORDINATE] as! NSArray
                        print(currentLocation[0], currentLocation[1])
                        print("\n")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("error")
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and the results are

```
55.55555 -55.55555555
55.55555 -55.55555555
```

You may want to consider additional error checking when nodes could be nil - some of the optionals for example could be better protected so in case they are nil, they don't break your code.

If the path's caused the issue you should accept Franks answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading `/users` and then looping over the child nodes under it. So that brings you a snapshot of each user, which as far as I can see should show two nodes.

But this code looks suspicious:

```
if driver.childSnapshot(forPath: ACCOUNT_PICKUP_MODE_ENABLED).value as? Bool == true {
```

Since the pickup mode status is in `driver_profile/isPickupModeEnabled`, you need to read from that nested property. So:

```
if driver.childSnapshot(forPath: "driver_profile/isPickupModeEnabled").value as? Bool == true {
```

The same applies to any properties you're trying to get from the nested node.

Comment: that is just a constant, it points to that path.  I tried it directly and still doesn't work

Comment: Please make sure that the code you share has no external dependencies that we can't know the value of. Having us guessing at values is a waste of time, and reduces the chances someone will be able to help you. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on how to do this, and why it is useful.